# surprendre + que

Tags: subordonnées, que

My question is about the following sentence, across which I came when reading the online edition of "Le Monde":

> L’escalade en cours ne surprendra que ceux qui s’obstinent à nier la réalité d’une spirale mortifère.

I assume that "surprendra" is in some future tense, but this is not what this question is about. My question is about the "que" that follows afterwards. My previous understanding had been that "que" is somewhat similar to "that", like for example "je pense que je suis drôle", which would translate into "I think that I'm funny". But apparently, this is quite wrong, because it doesn't make any sense here. Thus, what is the meaning of "que" in the above sentence?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Que* is part of the ***ne ... que*** compound.

> The escalation in progress will surprise **nobody but** those who...